# Capture a word `+` same word again but with a prefix

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

To all the Regex gurus

Any idea how to handle this beast

```
string = 'Position_Name [+|-|/|*] PrevYear Position_Name'
```

Looking for the Regex to match the occurrences of `Position_Name` (basically twice similar to a duplicate) but not really a dupe since it is followed by a special character and then by itself BUT with some prefix - here: 'PrevYear'. Means `Position_Name` is dynamic and could be any word (eg `Profit`, `Sales`, etc) but `PrevYear` will stay constant.

So how could I identify these lines where there's a position being mentioned twice with some math symbol in the middle (for now) and then capture those three elements since the plus could also be a `/` (divided by), a minus sign `-` or a multiply `*` as intended to be represented by `[+|-|/|*]` in my example.

PS: I do not mind programming this in two steps ... so first matching and then capturing - but still would need the regex to find these little gems (in hundreds of lines).

Elegantly finding dupes is not the problem eg via `\b(\w+) \1\b` but I have come to realize my capabilities are not sufficient for that combo.

Thanks on hints and support.

Comment: Maybe `\b(\w+)\b\s+[-+/*]\s+PrevYear\s+\1\b`? See https://regex101.com/r/KChQ4B/1

Comment: Thanks drop that as an answer ... gonna use `\b(\w+)\b\s*[-+/*]\s*PrevYear\s*\1\b` since the spaces around the math symbols are not always there. And the capturing splitting up into parts you also think I should prob do in a second step?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew One small thing though this will not grab `(Position_Name1 + PositionName2) / PrevYear Position_Name1` -> any ideas

Comment: Think this does the trick (for me) 
... `\b(\w+)\b\s*[-+/*]\s*\w*\s[-+/*]*\s*PrevYear\s*\1\b`

Comment: @GWD Seems to me from your description that the nature of the operators doesn't really matter, so I'd simplify. Something like this: `\b(\w+)(?:\W+(\w+))?\W+PrevYear (\1)\b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
\b(\w+)\b\s*[-+/*]\s*PrevYear\s*\1\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KChQ4B/3). *Details*

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more word chars
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `\s*[-+/*]\s*` - a `-`, `+`, `/` or `*` enclosed with zero or more whitespaces
- `PrevYear` - a fixed word
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\1` - same value as captured in Group 1
- `\b` - a word boundary.